# How do I show related products on GPMD theme

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using magento ver1.9.2 and GPMD.

I would love to ask that how to show related products on GPMD theme.I was able to show it when I use default one.However I cannot now.

I think I should put or rename some files.Do you have some tips or know how to do?I want to know it.That would be so helpful to me.

Comment: where do you want to display related product?

Comment: I just noticed this comment now.
Well,I would love to display under the compare list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display related products in Product view page Try adding

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="related" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
```

under the

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

like below in the catalog.xml

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" as="related" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
</block>
```

and in your themes product view.phtml

add code

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.product.related') ?>
```

where you want to display related products

Comment: Hello Piyush,

Could you please tell me more?I could find "catalog.xml" and add the 1st one under the 2nd one.
Then should I add the 3rd one in "view.phtml"?And where should I put 4th one in?
Anyways thanks for giving tips,your tips would help me.

Comment: I'm sorry but I misunderstood,
I should add first one under the second one.And then,I should add 4th one in "view.phtml".Right?
But it does not exist in products page..

Comment: check if product has related products assigned or not?

Comment: Yes,already have done it.

Comment: Where should I put "<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.product.related') ?>" in "view.phtml"?

Comment: currently put it  before the `</form>` tag. after you can move it as per your page design

Comment: I just put it under the "<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>".Is it correct?

Comment: yeah, it's correct

Comment: But it does not appear in products page.I changed a file where "/app/design/frontend/gpmd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml" .Is it correct file?

Comment: So I guess "catalog.xml" is wrong written.Is it in "/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout"?I just looked for it.Is there any "catalog.xml" in ftp files?

Comment: not in base/default, look for it in `app/design/frontend/your_theme/your_package/layout` in your case it will be `app/design/frontend/gpmd/default/layout`

Comment: Thank you for replying.But there is only "local.xml" in "app/design/frontend/gpmd/default/layout".Should I copy and upload a file which is "catalog.xml" in "app/design/frontend/your_theme/your_package/layout"?

Comment: you can add this code in your local.xml

Comment: You meant should I put "<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.product.related') ?>" in "local.xml"?

Comment: No, not that code  , the code which we were adding in `catalog.xml`

Comment: No that code which is "<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">" there.Where Should I put it?

Comment: in your local.xml , find if the code already exist in local.xml for `catalog_product_view`  action, if  it is there you can make changes in that according to the answer

Comment: Yes it does.Then should I add it in "<!-- Catalog Product View -->"?

Answer (score 0):

No idea about this theme coding.

But below code you can add wherever you want to show related products of the product. Here `$_product` is the product you want to show related products.

```
$related_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                  ->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=>$_product->getRelatedProductIds()));
     foreach($related_prods as $related){
      echo $related->getName(); 
              }
```

Comment: Thank you for giving a tip,Akhil.

Should I add it in just a phtml file?

Comment: Yes & be sure to replace $_product with your product object.

Comment: Which files should I put it in?

Comment: In GPMD theme if want to show in product page then put in: 
/app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

& later move this code where design looks fine. Development UI experience will be required. 

If helps feel free to upvote the answer :)

Comment: I just put it there.However it shows just code like $related_products =.....

Comment: How do I put it in?And where should I add it?For example like below <div> ,between php tags or so?